# o3d textures and transparency

Tags: graphics, transparency, textures, hud, o3d

I'm working at galery on o3d(plagin version) and I need make photos transparent. Photos are on hud. Here is some code:

```
g_canvasInfoPict = o3djs.canvas.create(g_pack, g_hudRoot, g_hudViewInfo);

alphaParam = g_canvasInfoPict.transparentState_.getStateParam("o3d.AlphaReference");
alphaParam.value = 0.5;

alphaParam = g_canvasInfoPict.transparentState_.getStateParam("o3d.BlendAlphaEquation");
alphaParam.value = g_o3d.State.BLEND_SUBTRACT;

alphaParam = g_canvasInfoPict.transparentState_.getStateParam("o3d.SourceBlendFunction");
alphaParam.value = g_o3d.State.BLENDFUNC_ONE;

paramOne = g_canvasInfoPict.transparentState_.getStateParam("o3d.DestinationBlendFunction");
paramOne.value = g_o3d.State.BLENDFUNC_DESTINATION_ALPHA;//or BLENDFUNC_SOURCE_ALPHA or BLENDFUNC_SOURCE_ALPHA_SATUTRATE or BLENDFUNC_ONE or BLENDFUNC_ZERO

g_fullPictCanvas = g_canvasInfoPict.createXYQuad(paddingX, paddingY, -14, g_fullPictTexture.width, g_fullPictTexture.height, true);

g_fullPictCanvas.canvas.drawBitmap(g_fullPictTexture, 0, g_fullPictTexture.height);
g_fullPictCanvas.updateTexture();
```

But it doesn't work. When setting paramOne.value = BLENDFUNC_ZERO photo displays (non-transparent)

paramOne.value = BLENDFUNC_ONE photo isn't displayed (full transparent)

So how to achive intermediate result?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the O3D plug-in is deprecated in favor of the [WebGL-based O3D](http://code.google.com/p/o3d/), is it an option for you to [migrate to the latter](http://code.google.com/p/o3d/wiki/GettingStarted#Modifying_an_O3D_plug-in_app)?

If so, you can inquire in the [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/o3d-discuss) about the transparency issue (if it still exists under O3D-WebGL). The developers are very responsive.